# Count how many functions use a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I know that decorators can be used to count how many times a function is used like this:

```
import functools

def counted_calls(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def count_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        count_wrapper.count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    count_wrapper.count = 0
    return count_wrapper
```

My usecase is slightly different. I want to track the following:

- How many times a decorator is used
- Which functions are decorated in a file.

Is that possible in Python? If yes, how can I do this?